# Microsoft SQL Server setup - how to specify password with SAPWD switch when it contains equal sign (=)?

Tags: sql-server, installation, setup

I've recently tried to install Microsoft SQL Server setup.exe using well tried syntax I used before, but run into error the because of '=' sign in my user password. See sample command below:

```
setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=Domain\User /SAPWD=Pass=word
```

Is there a way to screen equal sign or somehow specify password for SAPWD switch so that it has equal sign in it bud not causing error?

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the password in quotes?

Comment: As sorry that was quite silly for me not to try obvious and start searching for something advanced like screening of one character inside of password value instead of enclosing password in quotes :) I also need to edit question to specify that it is "|" (pipe) symbol and not "=" which causes error if password specified with no quotes

Comment: No problemo, added it as an answer in there just to have it for posterity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose it in quotation marks.